# Subnetting: Access 10.1.0.1 from 10.1.2.1?

Tags: vlan, subnet, ip-address, juniper, junos

Here is the newly configured vlan on my Juniper:

```
vlans {
    vlan1 {
        vlan-id 3;
        l3-interface vlan.1;
    }
}
interfaces {
    vlan {
        unit 1 {
            family inet {
                sampling {
                    input;
                    output;
                }
                address 10.1.0.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I set my PC statically to `10.1.0.2` with a subnet mask of `255.255.0.0` I can ping/access the Juniper.  However, if I set my PC to `10.1.2.2` with the same subnet, I cannot access it.

Clearly, I'm new to vlans and subnetting, but my understanding was that with a mask of `255.255.0.0` I would be able to access `10.1.*.*.`

What do I need to do so that my workstations can be set to `10.1.2.x` and access networking devices on `10.1.0.x` and servers on `10.1.1.x`?  Is there something I'm missing on the Juniper?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of http://tools.v8dev.net/IPv4_SubnetCalculator/10.1.0.0/, I changed `address 10.1.0.1/24;` to `address 10.1.0.1/16;` and of course it works now.

Comment: To correctly calculate, see the **Largest Common Network for Two Hosts** section of [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499).